# Group by subject in iOS Mail app

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

How do I make the default Mail app on iOS group by subject? I've enabled "Organize By Thread" but that doesn't help.

On my Mac (OS X 10.9.4):

[image]

On my iPhone (iOS 7.1.2):

[image]

Comment: It looks like Apple is making that feature in iOS 8. http://gizmodo.com/ios-8-the-best-hidden-features-that-apple-didnt-show-y-1586023628

Answer (score 1):

Mail on iOS, like on OS X, uses multiple factors to determine whether two or more emails are part of a thread. By not relying solely on the subject, Mail is able to keep a thread together even when other email programs/servers modify the subject (for example, adding "RE:"). This is seen by Apple as a feature and is not able to be modified.

Enabling Organise by Thread is the best you can do. If the emails still don't group together, then Mail is determining that the emails are not part of the same thread and this can't be changed.

Comment: But the same email list is grouped on OS X but not on iOS

Comment: @Oskar Yes, this may occur. Both Mail programs use multiple factors, but these may not be the same factors. Unfortunately Apple do not appear to directly explain what factors can affect thread detection and the behaviour does seem inconsistent. I presume you have the latest versions of OS X and iOS?

Comment: Yes. iOS 7.1.2 and OS X 10.9.4

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "multiple factors" theory, since as you say there is no documentation. What and how do you know about them? As far I know as soon you change even one letter in the subject line the link is broken.

Comment: @Buscar It was discussed in a WWDC session—can't find the session right now but it was a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, here we are in iOS 10 and Apple still has not address this capability.  The Apple Mail app does not support thread organization with Subjects that do not match the "multiple factors" that @grgarside pointed out.

Since this is not possible with the stock mail app, @Tonny suggested an alternative which is Outlook.  I have confirmed that Outlook does join conversations that have identical Subjects.

An example being the below which will work in Outlook but **not** iOS Mail:

- Alert Message
- Alert Message
- Alert Message

The below will work in Outlook and iOS mail:

- Alert Message
- RE: Alert Message
- RE: Alert Message

Outlook does not require the words "**RE:**" or "**FWD:**"

Answer (score 0):

As others said, that feature is not available in iOS 7, but it looks like it will be available in iOS 8.

Show related messages:

[image: ios 8 mail]

http://gizmodo.com/ios-8-the-best-hidden-features-that-apple-didnt-show-y-1586023628

Comment: I have now updated to iOS 8 and the problem is still there.

Answer (score -1):

You can use outlook. I had the same problem, but outlook does better grouping. Even in iOs9